# Docker-compose restart only updated images

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose "cluster" and sometime I update the image files for some containers. I rebuild them using `docker-compose build`. I would like to know if there is a way to restart only the containers that have a new image automatically. Ie. I don't want to do `docker-compose scale service=0 && docker-compose scale service=3` for all containers I updated.

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This command updates the containers that have a newer image (than the one currently running):

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps <service>
```

Comment: you have to stop service before issuing your command:
`docker-compose stop <service> && 
docker-compose up -d --no-deps <service>`

otherwise you will get 
`<service> is up-to-date`